# Windows Virtual Desktop in Azure - Including a Persistent Mapped Drive to Application

Tags: virtualization, azure, application-pools

I have set up Windows Virtual Desktop within Azure. Currently I am able to configure the application I have published to use FSLogix to apply a mapping to a VHD file on an Azure share which is great, but what we'd like to also have is a drive mapping for everyone who runs the WVD app.

I have a file share ready in Azure blob storage which is accessible and I can map it manually from the server by the UNC path. I have tried using "net use R: " and adding this to run from the registry (Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run) on the computer hosting the virtual app, but that doesn't open for for a user when they have logged on.

Online, I can only find information on the shared VHDs, but can't find anything on drive mappings in this scenario. Does anyone know where I can find this information or can you advise how it is done?

Comment: I still can't get this working. As a work around I can get the user to log onto the desktop session which will map the drive using a GPO and then when you open the application session it seems to map, but this really isn't ideal. We need to make the drive mapping available on first use of the app.

Answer (score 1):

I would be careful using the storage key if I were you - essentially, anyone who has that key assumes full control of the share and everything in it. You are no longer authenticating as "`<user>`", but as "owner of share". That could have terrible repercussions...

Comment: I agree. The problem is that the user based authentication just doesn't work because it would require authentication working from two domains. Microsoft Azure support are unable to give me an answer on even if it is possible or not.

We have NTFS permissions on the files. I will test from a non-domain joined computer and see how it is.

Answer (score 0):

Add a storage account and attach it to your blob storage. Once the storage account is connected to your domain, gpo will map for you.

Comment: I've already created a storage account. The issue is authenticating users from two different domains. We seem to be making a bit of progress by using the storage key.